# If Satan fell because of sin, then was there sin in heaven at that point?

Tags: sin, heaven, satan

Assuming that God cast Satan out of heaven because of his sinful pride and attempt to dethrone God, then doesn't that mean that there was, at that point in time, some sin in heaven? This seems like it would disprove the statement that there can't be any sin in heaven.

If there can, then, then why can't those dwelling in heaven think sinful things, too? It's said in the Bible that you can't be "unsaved", so then I'm guessing that means that He won't throw anyone out of heaven once they're in. What would he do in the event that someone sinned in heaven?

I asked my pastor this once, and he directed me to a passage in Ezra, I think; unfortunately, I don't remember exactly where...

Comment: This question is based on a lot of assumptions, about which Christians have countless opinions. Some of these assumptions aren't even so obvious (e.g. time may not exist in heaven, so talking about "at that point in time" may not even make sense). To be on-topic, it needs to specify a specific Christian faith tradition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sin is not in the atmosphere of a place, but in the person who disobeys God. Places don't disobey God, do they, so heaven itself does not have sin. It appears that you are thinking that sin is spread into the atmosphere like germs, and cause people to start thinking sinful things.

Sinners can entice others to sin by their actions and words. In Revelation 12, Satan is thrown out of heaven "and his angels," which implies that other angels have either fallen on their own, or were influenced by Satan.

However, Satan is still under the rule of God and is called back to heaven now and then, as we see in Job 1 and 2. So heaven at times is inhabited by sinning creatures.

Comment: I have heard a theory of multiple heavens, where there is battle and sinful creatures and another place where God resides, ever heard of it?

Comment: @Phil Paul mentioned a "third heaven" in 2 Cor. 12:2, but the Bible says no more about it. Anything else you may have heard is fanciful conjecture, possibly from New Age groups. (Like angels having wings -- only cherubim have wings.)

Comment: While our struggle with sin on earth is a lifelong battle, once we arrive in heaven the presence of sin will be a thing of the past. Recall the three P's of sin: penalty, power, and presence. First, God took care of the penalty of sin through Jesus' shedding of his redeeming blood at Calvary and his subsequent resurrection; second, God took care of the power of sin by giving us the Holy Spirit; and third, God will take care of the presence of sin in his kingdom without end. Sin cannot possibly rear its ugly head again (see Hebrews 9:28). If it could, Christ died in vain and God is a liar.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also important to think about the way things are now, and the way they will be in eternity. In the new heavens and the new earth, there will be no more sin; and Satan, the fallen angels, and the unbelievers will be in hell with no possibility of reaching the new heavens and the new earth. They will be separated from God forever (the second death).

Answer (score 0):

Well Luke 10:18 states And He said to them, “I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven.
So, I am not sure as to any proof or reference that God "cast" Satan from Heaven.

Another interesting thing to note is the reference to the book of Job, chapter 1, verse 6 that states; Now there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the Lord, and Satan also came among them. 
This to me implies that Satan is a Son of God and presents himself as one. Having been the highest angel of Heaven and keeping in mind that God co-exists without time and with time, Satan still then presents himself to God as a son of God.

In regards to the actual question of sin in Heaven we can deduce that if God is all as stated in Proverbs 15:3 The eyes of the Lord are in every place, keeping watch on the evil and the good. and again in Jeremiah 23:23 “Am I a God near at hand,” says the Lord,
“And not a God afar off? 24 Can anyone hide himself in secret places, So I shall not see him?” says the Lord; “Do I not fill heaven and earth?” says the Lord. Also in Daniel 2:22 He reveals deep and secret things; He knows what is in the darkness, and light dwells with Him. Im sure there are more but this one stand out the most to me Psalm 139:8 If I ascend into heaven, You are there; If I make my bed in hell, behold, You are there.
God is all, none and everywhere without being anywhere. He is so far beyond our understanding and perfect beyond measure so that its possible the concept of sin does not apply to Him. Who are we to say that God cannot do something? Is not everything created by Him? To include Satan? And who are we as mere men that we can understand the ways of the Lord? David says that if he makes his bed in hell, God is there. Also Heaven is brought down to earth (Revelation 21:2 Then I, John,[a] saw the holy city, New Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.) so therefore it is not we as believers that go to Heaven but Heaven that comes down to us when all is restored and made new and the old washes away.

The concept of sin, in my opinion being but a man, is anything that makes us turn away from serving God as the only One and perfect Lord. So sin can exist anywhere, at anytime if we turn from serving the Yaweh.

Comment: Could you please at least italicize the scripture references if you're not going to put them in quotes (which would render the original quotation marks single quotes, I believe [eg "'I don't have friends,' explained the sad banana."])? I would do an edit but the fact that you don't, combined with the way you've   presented the verse locations, makes it extremely difficult to determine what's what.